# Undefined reference to scene_render

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, cygwin, constants

Here is the following main function or my program

```
void scene_render(const struct Scene *s); 

int main(void) {                        //leave main as is
    struct Scene myScene;
    scene_init(&myScene);

    int keep_going = 1;
    while (keep_going == 1) {               
        cons_clear_screen();            //clear off-screen display buffer
        scene_render(&myScene);         //render the scene to display buffer
        cons_update();                  //copy the display buffer to the display
        cons_sleep_ms(ANIMATION_DELAY); //pause
        scene_update(&myScene);         //update the scene

        int key = cons_get_keypress();  //see if the user has pressed a key
        if (key != -1) {
            keep_going = 0;
        }   
    }
    return 0;
}

void scene_render(Scene *s)
{ 
    cons_clear_screen(); 
    for(int i=0; i<NUM_PARTICLES; i++) 
    { 
        particle_render(&s->parts[i]);
    }
}
```

When I run the makefile command on Cygwin, it passes the errors and starts compiling, but hits an error when it hits scene_render(&myScene);. It says that a reference to it is undefined. It refers to a variable in a function that is a const struct, while all other instances where &myScene is called are merely structs. Any idea what the issue may be? This lab is mostly about using pointers, if that helps.

The program (with assistance from external functions) should generate and throw randomly colored pixels around the command window, bouncing them back to keep them in the screen. Deleting the issue causes the program to compile successfully, but then loads a blank window that seems to do nothing.

Comment: Is `scene_render` one of your functions or from a third party library and if a library do you link in the library with `-l<name of library>`?

Comment: It came previously defined with the default lab setup, but it is in the programming and not in a library of any sort. Here it is when it is setup:                void scene_render(const struct Scene *s);                And here it is defined fully:                 void scene_render(Scene *s){
 cons_clear_screen();
 for(int i=0; i<NUM_PARTICLES; i++) {
  particle_render(&s->parts[i]);
} }

Comment: Is it in the same file or in a different file. If a different file, did you compile and link this other file?

Comment: Sorry, it is in the same file

Answer (score 1):

## Problem

With

```
void scene_render(const struct Scene *s);
```

you promise `scene_render` takes a `const struct Scene` as a parameter. By the way, you can discard the use of `struct` here. C++ knows `Scene` is a `struct`.

But the function that is defined is

```
void scene_render(Scene *s)
```

which takes a plain old, non-`const` `Scene`, so when the linker goes looking for a function that matches the promise it does not find one.

## Solution

Change

```
void scene_render(Scene *s)
```

to

```
void scene_render(const Scene *s)
```

to keep the promise. But make certain that [const-correctness](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness) is maintained throughout.

Comment: This seems to have helped and makes sense, but the coding still isn't completely compiling. The error is now saying I am making an undefined reference to particle_render(&s->parts[i], which is some of the coding in my scene_render function. I understand you saying about constant correctness, but I may not be doing it right.

Comment: @MichaelElder same deal. Make absolutely certain that the forward declaration of `particle_render` exactly matches the definition of `particle_render`. My concern with `const` correctness is if `s` is `const` in `scene_render`, it can only be used as a `const` parameter to functions called by `scene_render`. `const` is a promise that the parameter will not be changed by the function and that includes anything the function calls all the way down until the end.

Comment: It turned out the declaring it const was uneccesary. However, my coding still doesn't work. Currently it prints twenty letter F's, of a random color, and initializes them with random x and y directions. They operate fine until they hit the top or bottom of the command box window, where they either move into a left or right corner and stay permanently until the program is rerun. Is there any way to keep them bouncing correctly? The coding that controls the randomness generator, and then the bounds controller, are shown below.

Comment: void particle_init(struct Particle *p){
 p->partColor=((rand()%255)+1)/1.0;
 p->coord.x=(rand()%7900)/100.0;
 p->coord.y=(rand()%2300)/100.0;
 p->dx=((rand()%150)/100.0);
 p->dy=((rand()%150)/100.0);
}

Comment: void particle_update(struct Particle *p){
         p->coord.y=p->coord.y+p->dy;
         p->coord.x=p->coord.x+p->dx;
         if(p->coord.y==0) {p->dy *= (-1.0);}
 if(p->coord.y==79) {p->dy *= (-1.0);}
         if(p->coord.x==0) {p->dx *= (-1.0);}
         if(p->coord.x==23) {p->dx *= (-1.0);}
         
}